# Error procedimiento mysql: Procedure ... does not exist

Tags: mysql, stored-procedure, mysql-workbench

estoy programando un procedimiento para cambiar el pin del usuario y me sale el error 1305 Procedure.Cajero.cambiar_pin does not exist al ejecutarlo, he estado buscando pero no lo he podido solucionar.
Aquí les dejo el código:

```sql
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` FUNCTION `cambiar_pin`(id_usuario int, anterior int, nuevo int, confirmacion int) RETURNS tinyint(1)
BEGIN
    declare actual int;
    DECLARE pin_string varchar(100);
    SET pin_string=nuevo;
    if (length(pin_string)<>4) then
        return false;
    else
        select pin into actual from Usuario where id = id_usuario;
        if (nuevo<>confirmacion or actual<>anterior or nuevo=anterior or actual=nuevo) THEN 
            RETURN FALSE;
        else
            UPDATE Usuario SET pin=nuevo WHERE id=id_usuario;
            RETURN true;
        end if;
    end if;
END
```

Alguna sugerencia?

Gracias de antemano

Comment: Donde te sale el error? el usuario que quiere ejecutar esto tiene permisos?

Comment: El error me sale al ejecutarlo,es el único usuario de la base de datos así que sí tiene permisos, lo siento, estaba en la cama @gbianchi

Comment: Además no se porque me dice Procedure does not exist si es una función, alguna idea?@gbianchi

Comment: Ya se donde está el problema, lo dejo aquí por si a alguien en un futuro le sirve, no creo que pudierais ayudarme, ya que el problema viene de un trigger en el cual hago un call a esa función, de ahí que no exista el procedimiento.